# Master and content page in asp.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net

In my web application i am using master page concept, In master page i have login panel using this user can login, after login  login panel will not visible and a link button will visible as logout, it is working fine but in one of child pages (content page) i have login panel for login which is in update panel, when user login successfully in master page login panel is still visible , it is not suppose to visible, when i page refresh then login panel not visible and logout link button visibling. When i login in child page the login panel in master page also not visible and log out link button will visible can u help me in this case, thank you. This is code:

```
SqlDataAdapter  da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from xxx where (userid=@UserName or emailid=@UserName) and password=@Password", con);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserId.Text);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Login");
int i = ds.Tables["Login"].Rows.Count;
if (i == 1)
{
    LinkButton lnklogout = (LinkButton)Master.FindControl("LinkLogout");
    lnklogout.Visible = true;
    LinkButton linkmypro = (LinkButton)Master.FindControl("lnkbtnMyProfile");
    linkmypro.Visible = true;

    LinkButton linsynup = (LinkButton)Master.FindControl("lbtnSignUp");
    linsynup.Visible = false;
    Panel pnllogon = (Panel)Master.FindControl("LogonPanel");
    pnllogon.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two separate login controls? If I understand you correctly, you have one login control in the master page, and another in one of your content pages. What ContentPlaceHolders do you use? Maybe you could wrap the master page control in a ContentPlaceHolder that is hidden in that particular content page?

Comment: actually it is client requirement, no i am not using ContentPlaceHolder, i am using update panle Mr Christian Newsmark

Answer (score 2):

You are nearly there! You need to tell the updatepanel in the master page to update itself

```
UpdatePanel t = (UpdatePanel)Master.FindControl("UpdatePanel1");
t.Update();
```

I think you also need to set the UpdateMode to "Conditional" in the updatepanel

Don't forget to have similar code in the master page as so if the person logs in using the master page's login control then the child page should be updated as well.

good luck!

**edit:**

Sorry I forgot to mention that you definitely need to have an updatepanel in the master page around the login control as well. Otherwise this won't work

Comment: Mr.Mouhannad i dont have updatepanle in master page, but i have in child page in which i place the loginpanle for login

Comment: yes otherwise the login in the master page can not be re-rendered (until the entire page is refreshed)